# knife bootstrap windows winrm/ssh timeout

Tags: chef

I am trying to bootstrap windows server with chef-client. I am able to manually go in and install the Chef omnibus installer. Then I successfully installed the rubygem knife-windows for chef-client using the chef-client gem installer. When I attempt to execute

```
knife bootstrap windows winrm myserver.net
```

I receive time out messages as such:

```
    knife bootstrap windows winrm myserver.net
Bootstrapping Chef on myserver.net
Enter your password:
ERROR: Network Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (http://myserver.net:5985)
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

I'm not sure what that means, or what to check.

--EDIT--
Found out, that I had to run: 'winwrm quickconfig -q' on the target windows server to open the ports. Now I'm receiving a 401 error from the server.

```
C:\Users\CP_USER>knife bootstrap windows winrm myserver.net -x CP_USER
Bootstrapping Chef on myserver.net
Enter your password:
ERROR: Failed to authenticate to ["myserver.net"] as CP_USER
Response: Bad HTTP response returned from server (401).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run for Basic authentication :

```
C:\Users\Administrator> winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
C:\Users\Administrator> winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
```

See: https://github.com/opscode/knife-windows#nodes

Comment: Thank you, that's what did it. I also learned that you need to have an updated framework on the older 2003 servers then run those commands.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: `..WARNING: Switching to Negotiate authentication, Basic does not support Domain Authentication`. I have another SF question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27748504/2009612

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you can do a telnet from the workstation to the node you try to access.

This can be checked by typing telnet in a command prompt.

If telnet is not recognized as a command, then follow the steps:

```
1) Right click on "My Computer" > Manage > features
2) Click on "Add Features"
3) Select "Telnet Client"
4) Press Install buuton
```

It will take sometime to install.

Once it is installed, you can do the same telnet from your workstation's command prompt to the chef node

```
telnet <ip_address> 5985 //5985 is the port you want to do telnet.
```

Thanks!!!

Chandan