# Windows server farm on AWS/EC2

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, chef

We'll be deploying our application infrastructure (primarly Windows with some Linux components) on AWS/EC2 VPC. We'll be using Chef to handle provisioning and administration.

However, unlike Linux machines, Windows machines don't have SSH built-in and one is forced to resort to other methods of authenticating to get administrator access.

What's the best way to automatically grant our Chef server access to the Windows box? Some of the methods I found:

1. Include a default password in the user-data script of the instance

   - This seems insecure, then again, these computers are inside a private subnet of a VPC
2. Setup a domain controller server to manage all the computers

   - Research should that managing a Windows domain on EC2 can be a headache due to the possibility of losing EC2 machines randomly. This also seems like an unnecessary overhead for managing credentials of machines that will be added/removed frequently.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready to do some scripting, the best way to gather/provide Windows credentials is to use the AWS API (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonEC2/get_password_data) to "forward" the information to your colleagues for any newly windows instance created.

Otherwise, you can delegate some read permissions to your colleagues through the AWS IAM services which is a use management service to allow who you want to access some instances/groups/feature through customer aws credentials.
Some useful infos on the IAM concepts : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/IAM_Concepts.html#ConceptsAWSEntities

Answer (score 1):

The recommended and native way to control Windows nodes with Chef is to use WinRM e.g.

```
knife bootstrap windows winrm ...
```

This question has some details: [knife bootstrap windows winrm/ssh timeout](https://serverfault.com/questions/506467/knife-bootstrap-windows-winrm-ssh-timeout)

The *tl;dr* details for preparing your Windows nodes: https://github.com/opscode/knife-windows#nodes

In summary: for Linux nodes, use ssh; for Windows nodes, use WinRM

Comment: The issue with winrm is dealing with passwords of multiple severs. With SSH the private key is already authorized when I spin up a box. Windows boxes don't have anything built it unless I set the password in the userdata.

Comment: @Omar, you could use Windows domains (Active Directory) to manage the credentials centrally. We do this in combination with Chef, even for Linux servers, and it works fine (although it's a bit painful to get working).